# Jersey - The method accept(MediaType[]) in the type WebResource is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I try to do jersey client, but I get an error.
this is my code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Client and Handle to web resources
        String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWebapp/resources";
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI);

    // send a GET request with Accept header set to "text/plain"
    String response = webResource.path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
    System.out.println(response);

    // send GET request with a query parameter value for 'name'
    response = (String) webResource.path("hello").queryParam("name", "Pranabh").get(String.class);
    System.out.println(response);

    // send GET request to /hello without any query param
    response = (String) webResource.path("hello").get(String.class);
    System.out.println(response);

    // send GET request to /hello/{name}
    response = webResource.path("hello").path("Ranjita").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
    System.out.println(response);

    // send a GET request and get the response encapsulate in ClientResponse
    ClientResponse clientResponse = (ClientResponse) webResource.path("hello").get(ClientResponse.class);
    System.out.println(clientResponse.getEntity(String.class));
}

}
```

In line

```
String response = webResource.path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```

there is an error:
***The method accept(MediaType[]) in the type WebResource is not applicable for the arguments (String)***

What could be the reason?
How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: What version of jersey are you using and what version of Java? According to the Javadoc this should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The java compailer was an old one.
I update it and now everything work fine.

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Create an m object and pass it as a argument to accept:

```
MediaType[] m = new MediaType[]{MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE, 
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE};

String response = webResource.path("hello").accept(m).get(String.class);
```